# CloudFlare causing issues with VueJS

Tags: vue.js, cloudflare

I developed a web app in VueJS, but it seems to be having some issues with CloudFlare.

When a user is prompted with the Captcha verification screen, upon completing the verification the page loads, but it is blocking resources like my JS files.

However, if I say whitelist a certain country and access it, the page works as intended.

I've also had some issue when changing certain elements and the page not updating correctly, even when purging. I feel this issue is related to the one above.

(I'm also using SSL if that makes any difference.)

Out of curiosity, I've recently seen a lot of pages using a “newer” 5 second protection style page rather than a captcha. I was wondering if cloudflare offered anything like this as I feel the captcha gets very annoying for my users.

Thanks and any help is appreciated.

Comment: How does CloudFlare block your JS resources ? Is it presenting a Captcha for them too ? If yes, then you should report this to CloudFlare support.

Comment: @IVOGELOV Once the captcha has been entered, it goes to the site but this is in console (https://i.imgur.com/wJn86tU.png). No clue what is causing it but only happens when the captcha shows up. If it is disabled, then the site works fine.

Comment: Can you check the logs on your server (the one behind CloudFlare) and see what were the actual requests and were they actually served with 403 from your own nginX/Apache ?

Comment: Is your Firewall Access Rule Action set to `Challenge` or `JavaScript Challenge`?